# Sharepoint 2010 site access denied for Active Dirtectory group member

Tags: sharepoint

I created a blank site in **Sharepoint 2010** and in `Site Actions-->Permissions` I removed all the users and added an Active directory group which has me as member and few others.

After this I logged in as myself and it does not show that Portal on Left navigation. If I try to browse to that portal as myself it says "access denied"? I don't know where I am wrong. I am stuck from yesterday. If some one could help it would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the site collection administrator for the site and test using that user of change the user to yourself.

Given that the site is not visible in navigation (i.e. is security trimmed as you do not have permission to see it) and you get "access denied" directly, there is no evidence to second guess that the permission are just not set correctly.

Log in as the site administrator and try setting the permissions again, both using the group and using a user directly to find out where the issue is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

user that you install sharepoint with it can fix your problem.

1. you login with that account
2. then return inheritance to Default.
3. if you want to give permission to the  Active Directory Group,
   please do not remove site admins , site collection admin , portal
   admin or etc.